# Hide drag and drop area on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, drag-and-drop

I'd like to offer users a drag and drop experience when using a desktop computer where possible, but hide it on mobile devices where this is not an option.

After some research, it seems that iOS supports a lot of the modernizr classes you might use to detect this - e.g. the filesystemAPI, drag and drop etc.

Are there any test I can do, to see if a user can actually drag and drop files onto the relevant area? The easiest way I've found so far is to disable it based on the userAgent, but that's really not robust enough...

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/i)
      || navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
           $('#dragandrophandler').css('display','none');
};
```

Comment: Okay - the only real reason Modernizr is better than UA sniffing is because it allows browsers that update their feature set to work better with your code. So the question is, will you *ever* want mobile users to have this functionality in the future? If the answer is no, then UA sniff away! You'll never have to amend your code.